# NullPointerException when adding context menu to TreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am looking to add a ContextMenu to a TreeViewer following the example set out here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html#contextmenu however I get a NPE at the line

```
getSite().registerContextMenu(menuManager, viewer);
```

getSite() returns null rather than the IWorkbenchPartSite. Can anyone explain why the IWorkbenchPartSite is null or how I could initialise it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `getSite()` in preference pages. So I assume you are in an editor or a view.

The site is injected by the platform using the `init` method. When you call `getSite()` you have to make sure that you do it after the platform has called the `init` method.

A good place for context menu registration is the `createPartControl` method.

Comment: apologies, the question is badly worded. The treeviewer is declared in a subclass of ViewPart in the createPartControl method